# Regex Not Adhering to Value in Curly Braces

Tags: regex

I'm using the following regex in Notepad++ v6.6.8

```
\n(".*?",){14}""
```

It matches lines that it should, but it also matches lines that it should not. For example, I do not expect it to match the following line:

```
"Sold","421","421","67","1/9/2007 12:00:00 AM","","3","","","","","","","","1/9/2007 12:00:00 AM","","","","True","4601","1/3/2011 5:44:17 PM",""
```

However, it matches up through the second occurrence of the datetime. Out of curiosity, I changed the value within the curly braces to `15`, and it returned exactly the same match. Can someone explain to me why this is? I'm trying to get a quick count of every record in a CSV file where the 15th position is empty (`""`), and I think the result is off by a few thousand records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 14th instance of the first part of the pattern is matching `"","1/9/2007 12:00:00 AM"`. Just because the match is not greedy does not mean it won't extend if it needs to in order to make a match.

You might try something like

```
\n("[^"]*",){14}""
```

Or use the ^ anchor instead of matching the newline

```
^("[^"]*",){14}""
```

Answer (score 1):

`(".*?",){14}""` does a greedy match. This `(".*?",){14}` regex would match the exact 14 occurrences and the regex engine also tries to match the following `""` pattern. But there isn't a `""` after the 14th occurrence of `".*?",` in that place there is a string `"1/9/2007 12:00:00 AM",` which is not of `""`, so the regex engine moves upto the next `"",`. Once it finds, it matches upto that string in-order to get a match.

See the difference by removing the following `""` from the pattern. [Here](http://regex101.com/r/lC5sI6/4) and [here](http://regex101.com/r/lC5sI6/5).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Do you have any suggestions for how I can check if that 15th position is empty?

Answer (score 0):

According to [RegexBuddy](http://www.regexbuddy.com/), it does match that line. I'm not entirely clear what it should or shouldn't match given the example data but RegExBuddy agrees that it's a match.

[image: RegexBuddy showing match]

> Can someone explain to me why this is?

I think it's because `(".*?",)` -- specificly, the fact that you can match the quotes without any contents. This will allow any quotes to be counted against the quantifier.